# Release memory of object when popped from Stack in Android

Tags: android, memory-management

I am using a stack to manage Fragment in my application. Instead of using inbuilt feature by Android, I am using my own stack to perform some specific operations.

I use following code to replace fragment.

```
FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    if (bundleToPass != null) {
        fragmentToLoad.setArguments(bundleToPass);
    }
    ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragmentToLoad, "TAG_FRAGMENT");
    fragmentToLoad.setFragmentType(type);
    ///Local stack to manage the fragments
    activity.AddToStack(fragmentToLoad);
    ft.commit();
```

Based on some logic I pop from the stack. I am using

```
localStack.pop()
```

Is there anyway to clear the memory as soon as pop is called for the fragment?

Answer (score 0):

Nope.  Java is a garbage collected language, the system controls when the memory is cleared.  You can call System.gc to ask it to garbage collect, but there's no control over how much or what it cleans and what it leaves.  Also System.gc will pause the thread its on (possibly all threads) for an undeterminable length of time.